# Xcode6 Auto layout button is disappeared

Tags: autolayout, xcode6

On xcode6 in storyboard we have a new button to choose heigh/width of the device. I accidentally removed this button. How can I get this button back?

So I want to have the width/height button like this project in my storyboard again.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/igajjvjt7kel0rq/Screenshot%202014-11-17%2014.46.02.png?dl=0

Comment: Question and image is not clear

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour]. We expect more from questions which you can read in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I saw where it went wrong. I accidentally unchecked the "use size classes" in the file inspector